# Problema en mostrar y recuperar variables en jquery y php

Tags: php, jquery

Hola buen dia a todos,

Tengo un problemita que me anda molestando, estoy rescatando datos de un json y asignándolos a un input en este caso a un  de una tabla con su id correspondiente lo que pasa es que lo pinto con .html(valor) y lo muestra en la vista del cliente, pero cuando intento rescatar el valor general este me tira vacio, en el caso que le mande un console.log dentro de la función a la variable esta carga bien el valor pero estando fuera no.

Bueno en fin me tiene podrido este problemita y acudo a ver si ustedes pueden guiarme en como poder ver de forma global el dato para poder hacer otro requerimiento que sigue.

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme o guiarme seria de gran ayuda de ante mano gracias.

```
var form_data = new FormData(); 
form_data.append('id', '<?php echo $incidentes->ID_INCIDENTE ?>');
var pdoc = $('#doc_porc');
var pcom = $('#porcentaje_compromiso');
console.log('Al empezar' + pdoc.val());

function cargar_porc() {
    var numerox = 0;
    $.ajax({
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('historial/porcentaje'); ?>",
        "type": 'POST',
        "cache": false,
        "contentType": false,
        "processData": false,
        "dataType": 'json',
        "async": true,
        "data": form_data,
        success: function(form_data) {
            let number = parseFloat(form_data[0].PORCENTAJE).toFixed();

            pdoc.html(number + '%').val();
            pdoc.val(number);
            $('#porcentaje_modal').html(number + '% completado');

            console.log('valor dentro de la funcion ' + pdoc.val());

            // if (number == 100) {
            //     $('#cierre_m').css('visibility', 'visible');
            // } else {
            //     $('#cierre_m').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            // }
        }

    });
}
console.log('Al salir de la funcion' + pdoc.val());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Como se ve en la ultima foto este muestra bien el valor pero no por consola.]

Comment: Colocar el código en formato texto es mucho mejor que colocarlo como una imagen. Puedes revisar [ask] para formular mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: @cachique gracias bro ahí puse el jquery :D

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu problema exactamente y dónde es el problema? Ten en cuenta que las llamadas a Ajax son asíncronas (significa que podrías estar intentando usar/mostrar un valor cuando la llamada aún no se ha completado). Por eso, tienen un método  `success` dentro del cual puedes usar con seguridad los datos que traiga la petición, porque dentro de ese método sí es seguro que la llamada ha ocurrido. Si quieres usar los datos fuera de ese método, tendrás que crear una función y llamarla desde dentro del `success` pasándole en parámetro `form_data`  o implementar *callback*

Answer (score 0):

> .html( htmlString )
>
> ---
>
> When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.
> [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Lo que hace .html() es regresarte el contenido dentro de la etiqueta `span` y al tu pasarle argumentos lo que hace la función es reemplazar todo lo que esté dentro del sera reemplazado por `number + '%'`.

Si quieres agregar algún elemento debes de escribir la estructura completa

```js
pdoc.html(`<p> ${number} + % </p>`)
```